# RecyclerView kotlin don't remember selected items, after add next items

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Hello i have problem with my shopping List. I have RoomDatabase and recycler view to adding and reading my list. I create action when user click on button row change background, but after i add new items then don't see selected items. Where is a problem?

My Adapter:

```
lass ListAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
private var itemList = emptyList<Items>()
lateinit var viewModel: ItemsViewModel

inner class MyViewHolder(itemview: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemview) {

}


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    return MyViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.items_row, parent, false)
    )
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return itemList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentItem = itemList[position]
    holder.itemView.name_rec.text = currentItem.itemsName
    holder.itemView.amount_rec.text = currentItem.amountItems.toString()




    holder.itemView.rowLayout.setOnClickListener {
        val action = ListFragmentDirections.actionListFragmentToUpdateFragment(currentItem)
        holder.itemView.findNavController().navigate(action)
    }

    holder.itemView.btnDeleteee.setOnClickListener {
        val action = ListFragmentDirections.actionListFragmentToDeleteFragment(currentItem)
        holder.itemView.findNavController().navigate(action)
    }


    holder.itemView.btncheckbox.setOnClickListener {

   holder.itemView.rowLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBA5F"))
    }







}


fun setData(items: List<Items>) {
    this.itemList = items
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

My ListFragment:

```
class ListFragment : Fragment() {

lateinit var itemsViewModel: ItemsViewModel
private val args by navArgs<UpdateFragmentArgs>()


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false)


    //menu
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)



    //RecyclerView
    val recyclerView = view.recycler_view_list
    val adapter = ListAdapter()
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
    //ViewWModel
    itemsViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(ItemsViewModel::class.java)
    itemsViewModel.readAllData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { items ->
        adapter.setData(items)
    })




    view.floatingActionButton2.setOnClickListener {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_listFragment_to_addFragment)
    }
```

**Where is problem with save all actions who do user in list?**
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the selected item and in `onBindViewHolder` you have to check that the item for this position is previously selected item or not. If this is the selected item then change the background or make if default.

Actually the problem is as you are changing the background in onClickListener so when you are updating the itemList with `setData(items: List<Items>)` method RecyclerView reload all the visible items and your previously selected item loses its background

Comment: Thanks for answer and tips. I try remove my problem